# backed layer subclassed NSImageView setFrameRotation not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview

on backed layer subclassed NSImageView method

```
- (void)setFrameRotation:(CGFloat)angle;
```

not working! So if its a backed layer, i should be using...

```
CATransform3DMakeRotation (CGFloat angle, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z)
```

ok, it is working fine but the view clips the layer. So when i make it a non-backed layer (means setWantsLayer=NO), setFrameRotation works. But this time i'm not able to rotate the image around the anchor point. It rotates around (0,0). So how am i able to rotate the view around the anchor point, not the layer?

Thanks.